# Как отличить предлог с существительным от наречия?

Tags: предлоги, наречия, существительные

> Ну и пусть откажется, нам это **наруку**. Надень браслет **на руку**.

В подобных предложениях разницу я понимаю, потому что знаю, что между предлогом и существительным я могу вставить слово (что не всегда помогает) и что существует такое выражение (наречие) — наруку (кстати, к случаю). Однако порой попадаются интересные сочетания, где мне просто не хватает знаний, чтобы с уверенностью определить: наречие передо мной, либо предлог с существительным.

Comment: Лучше будет, если вы приведете конкретные примеры.

Comment: @Серж Я боюсь, что конкретный пример не охватит всех (большинство) случаев. Разобравшись с одним конкретным примером, я засомневаюсь с другим. Поэтому прошу дать общий план действий в таких ситуациях.

Comment: Вы правы: один пример не охватит всех случаев, так же как невозможно описать все случае в рамках этого сайта. Постараюсь написать в общих чертах.

Comment: https://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-89872-kak-otlichit-narechie-i-sushchestvitelnoe-s-predlogom

Comment: @Вавилен Вот здесь тоже неплохая  информация: www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=e7c41827-0f4b-49ec-955e-15a930eb31e7

Comment: Обратите внимание: ***на руку*** пишется раздельно и в значении наречия.

Comment: Для "понимания разницы" нет необходимости отличать одну форму от другой. Ни один носитель языка, услышав предложение, не станет мысленно вставлять в него проверочные слова. Такие приёмы применяются в интересах правописания и только в сомнительных случаях, а здесь написание в обоих случаях раздельное (хотя в некоторых старых словарях можно встретить и слитный вариант как допустимый).

Comment: @Alex_ander А ведь я был уверен, что слитно. Понятно.

Comment: @Alex_ander, как раз надо. Ошибки встречаются часто, даже у носителей языка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Помимо зависимых слов, отличить наречия от существительного с предлогом можно в контексте. Нужно задать вопрос к анализируемой  части речи вопрос. Если возможна постановка падежного вопроса, причем в его состав всегда входит предлог, указывающий на грамматическую форму, то это предложно-падежное сочетание.

Ср.: действовать(как?) втайне — со­хранить(в чем?) в тайне; сделать(как?) назло — жаловаться( на что?) на зло; вправду(как?) мокрый  — верить(во что?) в правду, стоять(как? каким образом?) насмерть — идти( на что?) на смерть; разбить наголову — надеть на голову

2. Нужно найти начальную форму словосочетания, в которое входит «неясное» слово. Если оно не является наречием, то предлога в начальной форме словосочетания не будет,

   например: **с начала лета — начало лета (с начала — существительное с предлогом).**

Ср. еще больше примеров.

**предложно-падежная форма**
Надень браслет(куда?)на руку. .

Слово отзовется(в чем?)в сердцах людей.

Ты написал не тот гласный(в чем?)в корне.

Наш поезд поставили (в сырой)втупик.

**наречие**

Ну и пусть откажется, нам это() на руку

Я сказал это в сердцах.

Ты был в корне неправ.

Вопрос поставил меня в тупик